# Eloquent grouped orWhere

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Currently have an Eloquent statement:

```
$contacts = Contacts::where('lname','LIKE',$searchquery.'%')
    ->orWhere('fname','LIKE',$searchquery.'%')
    ->orWhere('phone','LIKE','%'.$searchquery)
    ->where('active','=',1)->get();
```

It is treating it as

```
select 
    * 
from 
    contacts 
where 
    lname like $searchquery+'%' 
    or lname like $searchquery+'%' 
    or lname like $searchquery+'%' 
    and active = 1
```

what I am needing is

```
select 
    * 
from 
    contacts 
where 
    (lname like $searchquery+'%' 
    or lname like $searchquery+'%' 
    or lname like $searchquery+'%') 
    and active = 1
```

How do I go about grouping in Eloquent?  I have found a couple examples such as:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

But I am only used to Eloquent, not Laravels DB Query builder.  I tried adapting the Eloquent form to this

```
$contacts = Contacts::->where('active', '=', '1')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', $searchquery.'%')
                  ->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', $searchquery.'%')
                  ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchquery);
        })
        ->get();
```

No success as it does not recognize the `$searchquery` inside the function.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this is what you have to do:

```
DB::table('users')->where(function($query) use ($searchQuery){
                                $query->where('lname', 'LIKE', $searchQuery . '%')
                                      ->orWhere('fname', 'LIKE', $searchQuery . '%')
                                      ->orWhere('phone','LIKE', '%' . $searchquery);
                          })
                          ->get();
```

Note that I've put use ($searchQuery) so it can be used inside the closure

Comment: That worked!  Had to add the `connection('contacts')` before the table because its not from mt default connection, but works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use `orWhere` with multiple where clauses, you need to be careful!

Where clauses **after** `orWhere` doesn't effected to sibling where clauses **before** `orWhere` clauses such as `where`, `whereHas`, `whereDoesntHave`, `orWhereHas`

also you have to pass `$searchquery` variable inside to function in where clause using `use ($searchquery)`

```
Contacts::->where(function ($query) use ($searchquery) {
                $query->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', $searchquery.'%')
                      ->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', $searchquery.'%')
                      ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchquery);
            })
            ->where('active', '=', '1')
            ->get();
```